# Make .exe / .cmd / .bat executable from WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Recently I added config to `/etc/wsl.conf`:

```
[automount]
options = "umask=22,fmask=133"
```

After that I can't run any `.exe` (`cmd.exe`, `notepad.exe`) from WSL:

```
bash# ls -l /mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe
-r--r--r-- 2 user user 278528 2018-09-15 10:28 /mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe

bash# notepad.exe
-bash: /mnt/c/Windows/System32/notepad.exe: Permission denied
```

Is it possible to mark only Windows executables as executable?

Answer (score 3):

After i chage `fmask=33`, i can run `.exe` from WSL, maybe in WSL `exe` files need `+x` permission
[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem is, this makes ANY file executable, not just .exe, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Permission denied : you have to  as administrator.  Right click and run as administrator

[image]

Comment: do you still need help ?